# How to pass in the entire object into a function in a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

In my codebehind I have:

```
List<Products> products = 
rptr.Datasource = products;


protected string GetVariants(Product product)
{
  //
}
```

In my repeater I have:

```
<itemTemplate>

<li>  <%# Eval("Name") %>
<li>  <%# GetVariants(?????????????) %>

</itemTemplate>
```

How do I pass the product object to the GetVariants method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(Product)Container.DataItem` should do the trick

Comment: True, with the current code behind method it would need to be cast before calling. I'll edit my suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Instead of calling back into a method from your markup page, what about creating a new class for binding your Repeater? This avoids the issue all together.

```
public class RepeaterItem
{
    public string Name;
    public string Variants;
}
```

And then bind the Repeater with a new datasource:

```
List<Products> products = //Get Products
List<RepeaterItem> repeaterItems = new List<RepeaterItem>();

foreach(var product in products)
{
    repeaterItems.Add(
        new RepeaterItem 
            { 
                Name = product.Name,
                Variants = GetVariants(product)
            });
}

rptr.DataSource = repeaterItems;
```